# windows warning starting chrome with Selenium Python

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium

I've just started coding in python with selenium, but here is my problem :
When I start Chrome with selenium,I ve a warning message from windows (my computer is in french, but it ask if I want to reset my setting). And I would like to close that tab, to make my program continue on another tab.
But it seems impossible to close it. I tried :

- the Alert class of selenium, did nothing, the code just go through it
- Moving mouse to the cross, or to "dismiss" (with selenium obviously) just the same
- Switching tab, and close it (with selenium's control command), it doesnt change anything
- Open Chrome with my usual settings (still from selenium), with that mode i can t open my url anymore, but i dont have the warning message too ...

I would be so grateful if someone had an idea, or have already had that problem. In fact, i would just want to dismiss it, to make my program run, without having to close the window at the start.

Apologize me for my english, that's not my native language, but I swear that I do my best :/

Thank you very much to all, feel free to ask me more informations :)

AR

Edit: I can't forbid you to put a -1, but try to explain me in which way it deserves it, then, I'll try to correct me, or to give more details.

Comment: What precisely does the message say? It's ok to give it to us in French.

Comment: The message says :
"Outil de suppression de logiciel malveillants microsoft Windows souhaite rétablir vos paramètres.
Outil de suppression de logiciels malveillants Microsoft Windows souhaite rétablir les valeurs par défaut des paramètres Chrome. Suite à cette opération, votre page d'accueil, la page Nouvel onglet et le moteur de recherche seront la réinitialisés, vos extensions seront désactivées et tous les onglets épinglés seront supprimés. D'autres données temporaires et mises en cache seront également effacées, comme les cookies, les données relatives au contenu et les données de sites.

Comment: But what i find surprising is that it says that it comes from Windows software for malicious softwares, but the message clearly appears in chrome, in the parameters window :/

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Microsoft message to me. It is more like a message from malware. Incidentally, the -1 might be from someone who disapproves of your asking a question that does not appear to be about programming. Without an explanation, it's a stupid thing to do.

Comment: A malware ? but it happens only when I start chrome with Selenium on python, why would the malware be there only in that case ? Oh I shouldnt have use "programming" term ? But isnt python a programming language ?

Comment: Last item first. It's not that you should not have used programming terms. It's that this site is intended to be for answering questions about programming. Your question doesn't seem to be about that exactly. It involves Python, of course, but the question is not about coding in Python.

Comment: First item second. I didn't say I understood! :) But for Microsoft software to offer such a threatening message seems unlikely to me.

Comment: What version of Windows are your running?

Comment: Can you try to follow the advice in this?: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qO62rMPO05Q

Comment: my pc is turning on windows 10 64bits.

For the advices : chrome is updated with the last version, I tried to desactivate windows defender and the others windows security programm or update program, i also desactivated my antivirus, but when i start chrome with selenium : message come back; 

I opened Chrome from Selenium with my account setting, and i found something : If i m not using chrome with my session, it seems to work perfectly, but if i already have a chrome page (that i would have open manually) the page blocks at google.fr.

Comment: Then, I will try to create a new chrome-folder with new id and password, that i will create just for the program :/ I find that solution a bit dirty, and bizarre that Selenium didnt patch anything to counter it ^^ But thank you a lot Bill Bell :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Anyway, it's obvious I was wrong about that not being a message from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, even if I would prefer a patch from Selenium, because to my mind, that is a trouble comming from Selenium/python + windows + chrome combination : I ve created a new profile on chrome, add the X.add_argument("user-data-dir=...) It doesn't open my profile (I've maybe done a mistake in the path to the folder) BUT the warning message disappears with that line, all I wanted, then thank you very much Bill Bell ;)